# While running a test suite with Playwright on a Azure Devops pipeline, why doesn't the list reporter print the test steps?

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure-devops, playwright

I have a Playwright test suite that runs on an Azure Devops pipeline.
The agent OS on which the test suite is run is: Microsoft Windows Server 2022

On this pipeline I do the following (among other irelevant steps)

- checkout my project
- install a particular `NodeJS Version`
- perform a `npm ci`
- run the test suite using `npm run tests`

In playwright I'm using the `list` reporter  (`printSteps: true`) to print the test steps in the azure devops console.
After upgrading from Playwright 1.39 to 1.40 (and even 1.41.2), I've noticed that the test steps are no longer printed in the azure devops pipeline console.

I will post my findings below:

```
Azure Devops agent: Microsoft Windows Server 2022
Node version: 18.18.2
Playwright version: 1.39.0

1.1 should allow user to check ... › Before Hooks › beforeAll hook › Navigate (22.7s)
1.2 should allow user to check ...  › Create folder (9.1s)
1.3 should allow user to check ...  › Verify that folder (4.6s)
1.4 should allow user to check ...  › Add machine  (10.1s)
1.5 should allow user to check ...  › Go to ... (9.0s)
1.6 should allow user to check ...  › Go to ... (12.9s)
1.7 should allow user to check ...  › Click on ... (17.4s)
```

- the list reporter shows the test steps and the correct colors (green for OK, red for failure)

```
Azure Devops agent: Microsoft Windows Server 2022
Node version: 20.11.0
Playwright version: 1.39.0

1.1 should allow user to check ... › Before Hooks › beforeAll hook › Navigate (22.7s)
1.2 should allow user to check ...  › Create folder (9.1s)
1.3 should allow user to check ...  › Verify that folder (4.6s)
1.4 should allow user to check ...  › Add machine  (10.1s)
1.5 should allow user to check ...  › Go to ... (9.0s)
1.6 should allow user to check ...  › Go to ... (12.9s)
1.7 should allow user to check ...  › Click on ... (17.4s)
```

- the list reporter shows the test steps and the correct colors (green for OK, red for failure)

```
Azure Devops agent: Microsoft Windows Server 2022
Node version: 20.11.0
Playwright version: 1.40.0 (or 1.41.2)
```

The list reporter does not print any steps in the azure devops console
Also, the list reporter does not display any colors (green for OK, red for failure)

```
Azure Devops agent: Microsoft Windows Server 2022
Node version: 20.11.0
Playwright version: 1.40.0 (or 1.41.2)
I've also added PWTEST_TTY_WIDTH: '400' as environment variable 

1.1 should allow user to check ... › Before Hooks › beforeAll hook › Navigate 
1.1 should allow user to check ... › Before Hooks › beforeAll hook › Navigate (22.7s)
1.2 should allow user to check ...  › Create folder 
1.2 should allow user to check ...  › Create folder (9.1s)
1.3 should allow user to check ...  › Verify that folder 
1.3 should allow user to check ...  › Verify that folder (4.6s)
1.4 should allow user to check ...  › Add machine  
1.4 should allow user to check ...  › Add machine  (10.1s)
1.5 should allow user to check ...  › Go to ... 
1.5 should allow user to check ...  › Go to ... (9.0s)
1.6 should allow user to check ...  › Go to ... 
1.6 should allow user to check ...  › Go to ... (12.9s)
1.7 should allow user to check ...  › Click on ... 
1.7 should allow user to check ...  › Click on ... (17.4s)
```

As you can see, the test steps are doubled somehow.
The list reporter shows the correct colors.

Any ideas why this is happening? Or a more elegant solution?

Comment: So is it only the version thats changed here? Nothing else in the code?

Comment: Yes. The only 2 things that were changed, were Nodejs and Playwright versions. Based on the research that I've done, it has something to do with TTY. I've noticed that the list reporter was also updated from 1.39 to 1.41 (I mean in the libraries source files), so I'm wondering if it has something to do with that.

Comment: Hi, can you check [this similar issue](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/29156)? It mentioned it will not print steps if `process.stdout.isTTY` is false (there is no interactive terminal).

Comment: Hi @Miao Tian-MSFT. Thank you for the reply. Yes, I also concluded that this was the root cause (`process.stdout.isTTY` is false), and therefore I tried to force the step printing by using that env variable (`PWTEST_TTY_WIDTH`). The only problem is that now all the test steps are doubled in the output. Any clue if there are any workarounds for this? Or even better, how could I set the `process.stdout.isTTY` to `true`, on the azure agent?

Comment: Hi @MihaiTrifan, I'm sorry I'm not sure if there is a workaround. Maybe you can create a new issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues) to ask the issue.